# Getting akka's WebSocket id

Tags: scala, sockets, akka-http

I'm trying to make a Scala wrapper for the FXCM's REST API. I'm working on the authentification system and I find that I need to get the active socket's id to send authentificated requests as described in the docs:

> Authorization string containing
> “Bearer “, ID of socket connection
> and persistent token.
> 'Bearer ' + socket_id + api_token

After researching the answer in the akka documentation, I didn't find a way to get the id from a WebSocketUpgradeResponse.

Comment: It looks like that uses the socket.io/engine.io higher-level abstractions on top of a websocket.  There is a Play implementation of that protocol (https://github.com/playframework/play-socket.io) and an outstanding issue to extract an Akka HTTP implementation.  From a quick skim of the docs, it appears that the socket ID is either sent as a query parameter when opening the socket or is randomly generated by the server and sent through the socket after opening.

Comment: @LeviRamsey thank you for your advice. I was looking into socket.io's code and I found that the required parameter is `sid`. Now, I'm just searching where and how this id is generated (provided by the server or the client).